# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : file upload does not release memory

Tags: memory, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API in Visual Studio 2022, where in a controller is managed the upload of a file.

The code is:

```
[HttpPost(nameof(UploadAsync) + "/{projectId}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[RequestSizeLimit(52428800)] // Limit 50 mb
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAsync(int projectId, IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("NO_FILE_UPLOADED");
    }

    // some other verification, the magic number, and so on
    string fileNameWithoutExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    string strFile = fileNameWithoutExt + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + extension;
    var filePath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Uploads", strFile);

    try
    {
        string folderPath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Uploads");

        bool exists = Directory.Exists(folderPath);

        if (!exists)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
        }

        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        // System.Text.Encoding.CodePages package required otherwise err "No data is available for encoding 1252"
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Typically `.xlsx` files are uploaded that can be very big (see the `RequestSizeLimit`) because they are training data for AI.

In the posted code, there is no call to the code that processes the `.xlsx` content.

The problem is that already by loading the file this occupies a certain amount of memory, which we can see inside Visual Studio, and this memory is not released even if we can see that a certain point GC is working.

For example, the API occupies normally 80 MB of RAM on average, after uploading the memory grows to 400 MB, but it never descends to 80: after some uploads the Ubuntu VM for testing crashes because the occupied memory grows at each upload.

What could be the problem? And how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: You can try calling `stream.FlushAsync()` after `await file.CopyToAsync(stream)` is completed to ensure that all buffered data is written.
Or try setting <ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>
<ConcurrentGarbageCollection>true</ConcurrentGarbageCollection> To configure garbage collection mode .
You can also try some libraries that can handle streaming reading to process Excel files.